# Python: Fill in between graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plotted a waveform and a horizontal line that splits the waveform to upper part and lower part. Using fill in between the lines technique `ax.fill_between`, why is the yellow area appears not correct?
Please help. TQ.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline as make

xy = [(0,2), (1,3.5), (2,6.25), (3,8.7), (4,7.7), 
      (5,3), (6,2.5), (7,3.7), (8,4.3), (9,4.5), (10,2)]

X = np.array([x for (x,y) in xy])
Y = np.array([y for (x,y) in xy])

X_new = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
s1 = make(X, Y)
Y_new = s1(X_new)

rms = np.sqrt(np.mean(Y**2))

y_upper = np.maximum(rms, Y_new)
y_lower = np.minimum(rms, Y_new)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
#ax.plot(X,Y)
ax.plot(X_new, Y_new, label = 'wave')
ax.hlines(y=rms, xmin=0, xmax=10, linestyles='--')
ax.set_xlim(xmin=0, xmax=10)
ax.set_ylim(ymin=1, ymax=10)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.fill_between(X_new, rms, y_upper, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)
ax.fill_between(X_new, X_new, y_lower, facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Your 'yellow fill' is incorrect.  You are filling from a diagonal line.

Try:

```
ax.fill_between(X_new, [0]*len(X_new), y_lower, facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5)
```

Well, seeing the other answer, it depends on what you want to "fill between"...  :)

Answer (score 1):

You just had a typo here:

```
ax.fill_between(X_new, X_new, y_lower, facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5)
```

Should be:

```
ax.fill_between(X_new, rms, y_lower, facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: this doesn't work. it fills outside the waveform though.